# How to determine if a list is empty in R?

Tags: r

Essentially, I have a function that creates outputs of list(). I want my function to not create list(), but instead replace it with another value such as NULL or string. Is there a way to determine if a variable is assigned the empty list, list()?

Comment: `is.list(a) & length(a) == 0`

Comment: how about `identical(a, list())`? It doesn't differentiate between a non-empty list and some other non-list object, but if you really only need to differentiate an empty list vs *literally anything else` it works.

Answer (score 89):

Empty list is empty. It has no elements, but is still a list. List with no elements has length 0.

```
a = list()
if(length(a) == 0) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: You can shorter that using `!length(a)` like in javascript.

Comment: @jcubic this is very nice straightforward approach!

Comment: This is the most elegant answer so far, but I find it unfortunate to have to pay a linear cost for that. Even with a very long list, I would expect to be able to do a constant-complexity check of whether it is empty or not.

Comment: Worry no more, @Thrastylon : "lists" (Internally `SEXPTYPE`: `VECSXP`) in R are not the single/double linked list you might think of but essentially dynamically sized arrays. `length` of a `list` in R has constant complexity. Search for "R-internals" to learn more.

Answer (score 5):

```
!is.null(listname) & class(listname) != "NULL" & class(listname) != "logical" & length(listname) != 0
```

Comment: This will lead to errors, since it, for example, returns `c(TRUE, TRUE)` for `matrix`. (if used in and `if` statement that error would be `Error in if (!is.null(listname) & class(listname) != "NULL" & class(listname) !=  : 
  the condition has length > 1`. Independently, this is a bad answer as it gives zero explanation of the code, consider adding what the individual checks are supposed to be good for.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on the advice given by @jcubic:

```
    c <- {}
    !!length(c) #FALSE

    c <- {1, 2, 3}
    !!length(c) #TRUE
```

Comment: This code example is not valid R code.

Comment: Perhaps it’s not in R v4. Or maybe it requires some additional library. I used tidyverse quite heavily back in the days. I haven’t been using R lately, so I don’t remember unfortunately. Feel free to make some investigation and update my answer with specification.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the base R way: `length(a) == 0` there is `rlang::is_empty`.

However, replacing the return value of a function that usually returns a list with something else in some cases does not sound like a good idea and will make the function much harder to use without introducing edge-case bugs. Consider `unlist` or `x[sapply(x, length)>0]` to get rid of the empty list or patching the function called in downstream code that does not handle empty list as input correctly.