# Determine if a list inside a tibble is empty

Tags: r, list, null

I'm trying to get a boolean response to whether each row of a vector containing lists is empty.

I have tried the following, as per various questions here

```
g <- combined_plan %>%
  mutate(d = is.null(bck),
         e = length(bck),
         f = nchar(bck),
         h = is.list(bck)
         )
```

`Is.null` always gives false, even when I see `<NULL>` in the tibble, `length` is always `27561`, `is.list` always true. This seems to use the accepted options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183826/how-to-determine-if-a-list-is-empty-in-r)

I could use `nchar`, which gives a value of 4 when list is null, but this doesn't seem a great way.

How can I cleanly find if a list exists in the relevant location in a tibble?

Data:

```
structure(list(fwd = list(structure(c("44993002", "44993003", 
"44993004", "44993005", "44993006", "44993007", "44993008", "44993009", 
"4499301", "4499302", "4499303", "4499304", "4499305", "4499306", 
"4499307", "4499308", "4499309"), .Dim = c(17L, 1L)), structure(c("78110023", 
"78110024", "78110025", "78110026", "78110027", "78110028", "78110029", 
"7811003", "7811004", "7811005", "7811006", "7811007"), .Dim = c(12L, 
1L)), structure(c("27610013", "27610014", "27610015", "27610016", 
"27610017", "27610018", "27610019", "2761002", "2761003", "2761004", 
"2761005", "2761006"), .Dim = c(12L, 1L)), structure(c("44223002", 
"44223003", "44223004", "44223005", "44223006", "44223007", "44223008", 
"44223009", "4422301", "4422302", "4422303", "4422304", "4422305", 
"4422306", "4422307", "4422308", "4422309"), .Dim = c(17L, 1L
)), structure(c("27210034", "27210035", "27210036", "27210037", 
"27210038", "27210039", "2721004", "2721005", "2721006", "2721007", 
"2721008", "2721009"), .Dim = c(12L, 1L))), bck = list(NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)), .Names = c("fwd", "bck"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: `sapply(df, function(x) sapply(x, is.null))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate_each(funs(NULL_check = is.null, CLASS_check = class))
#Source: local data frame [5 x 6]
#Groups: <by row>

## A tibble: 5 x 6
#             fwd    bck fwd_NULL_check bck_NULL_check fwd_CLASS_check bck_CLASS_check
#          <list> <list>          <lgl>          <lgl>           <chr>           <chr>
#1 <chr [17 x 1]> <NULL>          FALSE           TRUE          matrix            NULL
#2 <chr [12 x 1]> <NULL>          FALSE           TRUE          matrix            NULL
#3 <chr [12 x 1]> <NULL>          FALSE           TRUE          matrix            NULL
#4 <chr [17 x 1]> <NULL>          FALSE           TRUE          matrix            NULL
#5 <chr [12 x 1]> <NULL>          FALSE           TRUE          matrix            NULL
```